# Swift Codable can not Customize only the desired keys

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I need to manually customize only one coding key for the following class

```
@objcMembers class Article :Object, Decodable{
        dynamic var id: Int = 0
        dynamic var title: String = ""
        dynamic var image: String = ""
        dynamic var author : String = ""
        dynamic var datePublished: Date?
        dynamic var body: String?
        dynamic var publisher: String?
        dynamic var url: String?

    }
```

so I have to add the following enum

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title = "name"
        case image
        case author
        case datePublished
        case body
        case publisher
        case url
    }
```

So I have added all the class members to the CodingKeys enum for just override the title to "name".

Is there any way enables me to add only the cases I want to customize to the enum???

Comment: which Xcode version you use ?

Comment: Xcode version 10.0

Comment: swift 4.2 ??.....

Comment: Yes.................

Comment: Short answer: no. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types (go to: Choose Properties to Encode and Decode Using Coding Keys)

Comment: No, you can't. If you have to map one key you have to specify all, but you can put multiple cases in one line e.g. `case body, publisher, url`

Comment: I think it's a pure bug , if compiled then Decodable should handle missed cases , on older versions it prevents compilation , may be because you add optional and default values

Comment: It's not a bug. It's optional, custom coding keys do exist or not.

Comment: @ Desdenova But The keys have to be existed all although I do not need all of them to be customized.

Comment: @SamehDos Yes, that's the point. If you conform to protocol `CodingKey` you have to map everything as pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

### For Xcode 9.3 or later

You can achieve that by combining 3 things:

- A `GenericCodingKeys` struct that allows us to make a coding key with arbitrary string value.
- A function that maps the JSON key to your property's name (`name` → `title`)
- Setting [`keyDecodingStrategy = .custom(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2949119-keydecodingstrategy) on the `JSONDecoder` object

Try this:

```
import Foundation

// A struct that allows us to construct arbitrary coding keys
// You can think of it like a wrapper around a string value
struct GenericCodingKeys: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
}

@objcMembers class Article: NSObject, Decodable {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var image: String = ""
    dynamic var author : String = ""
    dynamic var datePublished: Date?
    dynamic var body: String?
    dynamic var publisher: String?
    dynamic var url: String?

    static func codingKeyMapper(path: [CodingKey]) -> CodingKey {
        // `name` is the key in JSON. `title` is your property name
        // Here, we map `name` --> `title`
        if path.count == 1 && path[0].stringValue == "name" {
            return GenericCodingKeys(stringValue: "title")!
        } else {
            return path.last!
        }
    }
}

let json = """
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A title",
    "image": "An image",
    "author": "Any author",
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

// Configure the decoder object to use a custom key decoding strategy
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom(Article.codingKeyMapper)
let article = try decoder.decode(Article.self, from: json)

print(article.title)
```